# determing x,y increase by angle?

Tags: trigonometry

If I had a position of 0,0 and I had an angle of 45 degrees (or any number) and my velocity was 1  what would be the x,y increase?

For example if I had a 90 degree angle, and I had a velocity of 1.  Then because my angle is straight up, my increase would be 1y and 0x.

Not sure if this makes sense, I am programming a small game, that shoots on any angle, and I need to pass it x and y coordinates so it shoots on the same angle.

Thanks!

Just need the equation, or a tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $(0,0)$ at angle $\theta$ at velocity $1$ you get to $x=\cos\theta$, $y=\sin\theta$. You know trigonometry?

Comment: used to! so if I had an angle of 45 it would just be x=cos45 and y=sin45   seems pretty straight forward.

So x=0.707  and y = 1

Comment: @Johnny, yes.$ $

Comment: @Johnny - $x$ looks fine by $y $ does not, as you should find $\cos 45 = \sin 45 = 1/\sqrt{2} \approx 0.707$

Comment: oops, you are right, I did tan.  is Y always going to be sin? If so why is that?

Comment: It is the definition of the sine as opposite/hypotenuse.  Since your angle is measured from the $X$ axis, $v_x=v \cos(\theta), v_y=v \sin (\theta)$

Comment: When I wrote "yes" above, it was to the $x=\cos45^\circ$, $y=\sin45^\circ$, not to the $x=0.707$, $y=1$ (which I didn't see at the time, perhaps it wasn't there at the time).